# Capitalize span with previous span having a content property in:before

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<style>
.caps {
 text-transform: capitalize
}
.stuffBefore:before {
 content: 'a';
}
</style>

<div class="caps"><span class="stuffBefore"></span>
<span>stuff after</span></div>
```

What I'm basically trying to achieve is to show

aStuff After

but what i actually get is

Astuff After

I can't add a space between "a" and "stuff" (get this as an example of the problem, the real problem is a little more complex) but i thought the "span" tag would act as a separator, like the whitespace.
Can I achieve it by adding further CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is one way :*

**JsFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/8vzmv06p/

```css
.caps {
 text-transform: capitalize;
 position:relative;
}
.caps > span{
 float:left;
}
.stuffBefore:before {
 content: 'a';
 text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caps"><span class="stuffBefore"></span>
<span>stuff after</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.caps > span{
 float:left;
}
.stuffBefore:before {
 content: 'a';
}
.stuffBefore + span {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="caps"><span class="stuffBefore"></span><span>stuff after</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```css
.caps {
 text-transform: capitalize
}
.stuffBefore:before {
 content: 'a';
 float: left;
 text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caps"><span class="stuffBefore"></span>
<span>stuff after</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.stuffBefore` `span`? If not necessary you can simplify your code:

```css
.caps span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.caps span:before {
  content: 'a';
  text-transform: none;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="caps">
  <span>stuff after</span>
</div>
```

Even without `span`:

```css
.caps  {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.caps:before {
  content: 'a';
  text-transform: none;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="caps">
  stuff after
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the .stuffBefore span.